# Plutus: how to obtain wallet details. Do I have to use the wallet web interface or there is some direct library call?

Tags: plutus, wallet

I need to know the amount of Ada remaining in an account in a off-chain Haskell plutus program. Should I use the wallet web interface of the kind:

http://localhost:8090/v2/wallets/$WALLET_ID

or there is some direct Plutus library call or haskell serialization library for that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using React in the front-end,you can use the serialization library created by emurgo.After installing their library you first connect to a wallet like this. I will be connecting to a yoroi wallet , for any other wallet you can just swap out the name and it works same way.

```
import {Value} from "@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-asmjs"
let Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer
```

```
const [balance,setBalance] = useState()
let API = ""
const connectToWallet = async () =>{
        try {
            API = await window.cardano.yoroi.enable();
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
}
```

After you enable it , it will return a api key. You can then use the API key to get the balance of wallet.

```
    getBalance = async () => {
        try {
            const balanceCBORHex = await API.getBalance();
            const balance = Value.from_bytes(Buffer.from(balanceCBORHex, "hex")).coin().to_str();
            setBalance(balance)

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @hang9921 that would be useful in the future. At this moment I'm programming in Haskell in the server. I need to access a server wallet like daedalus or the  cardano-wallet in https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps

Comment: Have you check out Cardano-transaction-library. https://github.com/Plutonomicon/cardano-transaction-lib/blob/develop/doc/getting-started.md